# How to print the return value of a function using printf()?

Tags: c, printf

### Update:

The original code looked a lot like this:

```
// printf(printf(););

#include <string>

int main()
{
   printf(printf("Hello, WORLD!"););
}
```

However, in the original post, `printf("Hello, WORLD!")` was assigned to a variable, x.

### Intended questions:

1. How do I call the return value of a function within a function?  As a beginner, learning to reference a string variable using %s, I wondered how to reference a the return value of a function (for example, if the return value were a string, would I still use %s).
2. What does "called to print" mean?  I think a simplistic explanation is: the string is put into memory and assigned an address, and the class definition tells the compiler to look up the location in memory based on the class's input-argument definition; so, the address in memory is called to print by the compiler.
3. Is the first argument of `printf()` also the return value of `printf()` such that `x == "Hello, World!"` is true in `x = printf("Hello, World!")`?

### Original post:

I'm looking at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

it says: `int printf ( const char * format, ... );`, but it doesn't define `...`.  So, I don't know what `...` is referencing.  I wrongly assumed that meant `( const char * format, const char * format, const char * format, ~`.  But in fact, I can't decipher the meaning based on guessing and reading.

Using this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    str x = printf("Hello, World!\n");
    printf("x has %d characters.\n", x);
    //"x has %d characters.\n" appears first, x appears second.

    return 0;
}
```

We see the result:

```
Hello, World!
x has 14 characters.
```

When I expected:

```
x has 14 characters.  //because this appears first.
Hello, World!         //because this appear second.
```

Because `x` comes after `x has 14 characters.`.

Someone please explain why `./a.out` is giving me the results in backwards order (using gcc and shell in Ubuntu); furthermore, eclipse is shown to give the results in this same backward order.

Perhaps another way to rephrase the question would be: **where is `"Hello, World!\n"` being called to print?**

Comment: Why would you expect `Hello, World!` to be printed second when you call `printf("Hello, World!\n");` first??? Stuff appears in the order you print them.

Comment: `printf("a", "b", "c")` does not return `a b c`. I have failed to understand your question.

Comment: `printf("a", "b", "c");` will *print* `a` and *return* 1.

Comment: Re "*where is `"Hello, World!\n"` being called to print?*", Line 4 (`printf("Hello, World!\n")`)

Comment: @ikegami `printf("Hello, World!\n")` is being assigned to x.  What doesn't make sense is saying that it's "called to print".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call [`printf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf), it will print whatever string you pass it as an argument. 
So, you are getting the prints on console in the same order you placed them in your code.

**Update after the edit from OP:**

I still don't quite comprehend what you meant by `//because this appear second.` comment there.

```
x has 14 characters.  //because this appears first.
Hello, World!         //because this appear second.
```

My take of the problem is, What you are trying to do is get an explanation on why `Hello World` is printed first and then `x has 14 characters.` is getting printed.

I can't tell this in simplest of the words than, "Because, when the code is getting executed, processor encounters first call to `printf()` function with a string argument `"Hello World\n"`. So it dumps that on console.
Then comes the second call with `printf("x has %d characters.\n", x);`, eventually dumping that on the console later."

Obviously, the value of `x` is `14` because count of chars in string `Hello World!` is 13+1 (i.e. 14)

**Now the confusion:**
If you think that you just defined `x` as `printf("Hello World!\n")`, then thats a wrong assumption.
With `int x = printf("Hello, World!\n");` statement, you, in fact declared an `int` variable `x` and initialized (or assigned) it with value `return`ed by `printf("Hello World\n");`, which is `14`.

Comment: I agree, and its true that many of the developers won't stand the tone when I say "Compilers do not execute your code, they compile it", but that is the plain technical truth. Its not my concern if the question is edited, as long as its there in the question when I write up an answer.

Comment: Moreover, had I suggested the edit to remove the statements related compiler from the Original Post, because they were technically wrong, the reviewers would have rejected it because that would be an attempt to change the original technical details of the post, no matter wrong or right. Not in your case, but they usually reflect the overall understanding of the person who is asking the question.

Comment: It does make sense.  `x` is the return value, which is `14`.  I **thought** x was "hello world".  And I further thought that `printf(a, x)` would return `a x`; therefore first (`a: x has 14 characters\n`.) second (`x: Hello, World!\n`).  However, what we are seeing is the first statement being called and returning a value to someplace followed by the second statement printing `x has 14 characters`, *comparing %d to the second argument*.  From the manual, I can't see how it works, specifically.  But as far as I can see *the second argument in printf is compared in the first argument*.

Comment: Well, the information you have provided, including the persnickety (forgive me, somewhat annoying) info in the original answer, was all very useful and helped me to learn some.  I often post some low-quality questions by mistake, and it's very stressful to get some of the responses.  But I'm doing my best, you know?  I honestly believe turning a low-quality question into a high-quality question is venerable and will get you a lot of points: have a try, you might be surprised.  But you know, do whatever you feel is right.  I spend a few days thinking about questions and do research and still...

Comment: @Wolfpack'08: Alright, I am glad that you could learn something out of it and may have resolved your doubt. I'll take your feedback about avoiding some remarks that are necessary but might feel annoying. I'll see to it that I put them across in a humbler way than I used to. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

`Hello, World!` appears first because you printed it first.

---

First (on line 4), you call `printf` as follows: `printf("Hello, World!\n")`. It prints `Hello, World!` and a line feed. You save the value returned by the call (`14`, the number of characters printed) in `x`.

Then (on line 5), you call `printf` as follows: `printf("x has %d characters.\n", x)`. It prints `x has 14 characters.` and a line feed. The returned value is discarded.

---

Note that `x` has no characters; it has a number. Specifically, it has the number returned by the first call to `printf`, which is the number of characters it printed.

The following gives the output you desire:

```
const char* msg = "Hello, World!";
size_t len = strlen(msg);
printf("msg has %zu characters.\n", len);
printf("%s\n", msg);
```

Comment: I didn't call `printf("Hello, World!\n"`.  I only defined it as x.

Comment: There is no point at which I've called `"Hello, World!\n"` that is abundantly clear or intentional.

Comment: Re "*I didn't call `printf("Hello, World!\n"`.*", Yes you did. On line 4.

Comment: Re "*I only defined it as x*", That makes no sense.

Comment: Re "*There is no point at which I've called `"Hello, World!\n"`*", I agree. That's not a function, so you couldn't possibly have called it.

Comment: If I was calling it to print, then it would look like `printf("Hello, World!\n")` not `int x = printf("Hello, World!\n")`.

Comment: That's like saying there's no addition in `5*(6+7)` because an addition would look like `6+7`.

Comment: In fact, it's exactly saying x = 5 means x = 5 (not x = a printer printing 5).  You're literally saying "line 4 says printf("Hello, World!\n")" and ignoring `int x =`.

Comment: `printf(...)` is a call to `printf` (just like `6+7` performs an addition), and `printf` prints to stdout when called and returns the number of bytes printed (just like 6+7 performs addition and returns 13).  You asked for our help, so please stop disputing this.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 calling `x = printf(...` is __exactly__ the same as `printf(...`, but in the latter case we simply ignore the return value of `printf`, while in the first case we also assign the return value of `printf` to x. Maybe you should read the chapter dealing with functions in your C textbook.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I understand.  Thank you.  Now it makes a lot of sense.  If you post your answer, it will be marked as correct.  If you can help me to understand where you go this information so that I can locate such information on my own in the future, I would greatly appreciate your saving me the headache of using QA sites.  Thank you, sir.  P.S. - This is the chapter dealing with functions.  As you know, this field is riddled with incomplete or low-quality explanations.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 All comments and answers to this question make sense. I got this information the first time I studied C a long time ago by reading the chapter dealing with functions in my C textbook.

Comment: No, "I only defined it as x" doesn't make sense. `#include <stdio.h>` defined `printf`, and `int x` defined `x`.

Comment: Re "*You're literally saying "line 4 says printf("Hello, World!\n")"*", Don't lie. I never said anything of the kind. I said you called `printf("Hello, World!\n")` on line 4. I didn't say you didn't do anything else on line 4. (In fact, I said you assigned the result of call to `x`, which is the number of bytes printed.)

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 The [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) is also pretty clear: _printf writes the C string pointed by format to the standard output (stdout)...._, and _Return Value: On success, the total number of characters written is returned...._

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to get the length of the string with `printf` but it also print's out the given string while returning printed characters length. It's not what you want.

You can use `strlen` instead of `printf` to get the length of a string without printing it to the output.

```
char *str = "Hello, World!\n";
int x = strlen(str);
printf("x has %d characters.\n", x);
printf(str);
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this little program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(int bar)
{
  printf("Foo %d\n", bar);
  return 42;
}

int main() {
  int x = foo(12);           // we call the foo function which prints "Foo 12"
                             // the return value of foo is assigned to x"
  printf("Hello World.\n");  // we print "Hello World"
  printf("x = %d\n", x);     // we print "x = 42"
}
```

The output is:

```
Foo 12
Hello World.
x = 42
```

If you understand this little program, you should understand also the output of *your* program.

In your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int x = printf("Hello, World!\n");   // you call printf which prints ("Hello World!") 
                                         // and the return value of printf is assigned to x

    printf("x has %d characters.\n", x); // then we print "x has 14 characters"

    return 0;
}
```

Hence the output is

```
Hello, World!
x has 14 characters.
```

Answer (score -1):

because you called x = printf("Hello, World!\n") first; 
the system will do the printf in output and also assign x = 14

therefore you have your second printf.